# derivate by definition $f(z)=\frac{8z^2-i}{z^2+1}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits, derivatives

derivate by definition of taking the limit $z\to z_0$ to this funciton $f(z)=\frac{8z^2-i}{z^2+1}$
I have tried to derivate by definition but always got stucked. my last attempt got me this far: $\lim_{z\to z_0}=\frac{5z^2-11z_0^2}{(z^2+1)(z_0^2+1)(z-z_0)}$

Comment: @Ramanujan $f'(z_0)= lim{z/to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$

Comment: How did you get to that expression? The expression is wrong

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\frac{8 z^2-i}{z^2+1}-\frac{8 z_0^2-i}{z_0^2+1}}{z-z_0}=[\ldots]=\frac{\frac{(8+i) (z-z_0) (z+z_0)}{\left(z^2+1\right) \left(z_0^2+1\right)}}{z-z_0}\\=\frac{(8+i) (z+z_0)}{\left(z^2+1\right) \left(z_0^2+1\right)}$$
as $z\to z_0$ we get
$$f'(z_0)=\frac{2z_0(8+i)}{(z_0^2+1)^2}$$